# JS: Как получить событие добавленного элемента?

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование

Доброе время суток!

Если элемент через append, как получить его события и this на него?

bind/change/on - не работают.

Отрабатывает только:

```js
$(document).on({
     change: function() {
     }
 }, '.napolnenie-el-material');
```

но при this, я не могу получить поля добавленного элемента = undefined.

Answer (score -1):

Необходимо использовать функцию jquery live. Она задает обработчик события, в том числе и на те элементы, удовлетворяющие заданному селектору, которые будут добавлены после объявления.

```
$("#id").live(function() {
    alert($(this).val());    
});
```

Comment: Метод [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) считается устаревшим с версии 1.7 и был удалён в версии 1.9. Сейчас актуальна версия 3.1.

Answer (score -1):

Вам нужно что-то вроде этого:

```
$(document).on('change', '.napolnenie-el-material', function() { /* ... */ });
```

Второй аргумент в методе [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) принимает селектор, на который будут вешаться события даже если элементы, попадающие под селектор, были добавлены динамически через [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/), [`prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/), [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) и любым другим способом.